Create new date columns based on matching vector
I am trying to simulate visit schedules for participants in a study. I will start with a dataframe of participants and first visit dates, and my goal is to create columns with the dates of later visits.
Participants will have study visits at certain intervals after their first visit. The intervals depends on the study arm. I have stored these intervals in vectors.
I want to end up with a dataframe where each row is a participant and there are date columns for each visit number. I am able to accomplish this with case_when, but I have many visits and arms (not shown in the reprex). The output from the example works fine, but I am looking for a more robust and parsimonious solution.
library(dplyr)
# set up schedules
arm1 <- c(0, 14, 28)
arm2 <- c(0, 14, 19, 180)
arm3 <- c(0, 14, 28, 32)

# simulate dataframe for 30 participants
d0 <- data.frame(
  ids = seq(1:30),
  studyarm = rep(c("arm1", "arm2", "arm3"), 10),
  date_visit1 = rep(seq(as.Date("2024-06-01"), as.Date("2024-06-10"), by = 1)))

# add visit dates depending on arm
d1 <- d0 %>% 
  mutate(
    date_visit2 = case_when(
      studyarm == "arm1" ~ date_visit1 + arm1[2],
      studyarm == "arm2" ~ date_visit1 + arm2[2],
      studyarm == "arm3" ~ date_visit1 + arm3[2]
    ),
    
    date_visit3 = case_when(
      studyarm == "arm1" ~ date_visit1 + arm1[3],
      studyarm == "arm2" ~ date_visit1 + arm2[3],
      studyarm == "arm3" ~ date_visit1 + arm3[3]
    ),
    
    date_visit4 = case_when(
      studyarm == "arm1" ~ date_visit1 + arm1[4], # correctly returns NA
      studyarm == "arm2" ~ date_visit1 + arm2[4],
      studyarm == "arm3" ~ date_visit1 + arm3[4]
    )
  )
  


One option is to keep arms in a frame, interval columns named as date_visit2 ... 4, this can then be joined to d0 by studyarm and all intervals can be transformed to dates with a single mutate(across(...)) call.
library(dplyr)

# set up schedules
arms <- tribble(
  ~arm,  ~date_visit2, ~date_visit3, ~date_visit4,
  "arm1", 14, 28, NA,
  "arm2", 14, 19, 180,
  "arm3", 14, 28, 32
)

# simulate dataframe for 30 participants
d0 <- data.frame(
  ids = seq(1:30),
  studyarm = rep(c("arm1", "arm2", "arm3"), 10),
  date_visit1 = rep(seq(as.Date("2024-06-01"), as.Date("2024-06-10"), by = 1)))

d0 %>% 
  left_join(arms, by = join_by(studyarm == arm)) %>% 
  mutate(across(date_visit2:date_visit4, ~date_visit1 + .x)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 30 × 6
#>      ids studyarm date_visit1 date_visit2 date_visit3 date_visit4
#>    <int> <chr>    <date>      <date>      <date>      <date>     
#>  1     1 arm1     2024-06-01  2024-06-15  2024-06-29  NA         
#>  2     2 arm2     2024-06-02  2024-06-16  2024-06-21  2024-11-29 
#>  3     3 arm3     2024-06-03  2024-06-17  2024-07-01  2024-07-05 
#>  4     4 arm1     2024-06-04  2024-06-18  2024-07-02  NA         
#>  5     5 arm2     2024-06-05  2024-06-19  2024-06-24  2024-12-02 
#>  6     6 arm3     2024-06-06  2024-06-20  2024-07-04  2024-07-08 
#>  7     7 arm1     2024-06-07  2024-06-21  2024-07-05  NA         
#>  8     8 arm2     2024-06-08  2024-06-22  2024-06-27  2024-12-05 
#>  9     9 arm3     2024-06-09  2024-06-23  2024-07-07  2024-07-11 
#> 10    10 arm1     2024-06-10  2024-06-24  2024-07-08  NA         
#> # ℹ 20 more rows

Created on 2024-05-03 with reprex v2.1.0

An approach that imports the armX values per row, then using purrr::map to perform the calculations per armX value, length given by the max length of all armX vectors.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

Seq <- 1:max(lengths(list(arm1, arm2, arm3)))

d0 %>% 
  mutate(studyarm_val = purrr::map(studyarm, ~ eval_tidy(parse_expr(.x)))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(date_visit = list(purrr::map(Seq, ~ 
           date_visit1 + unlist(studyarm_val)[.x]))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(date_visit, names_sep="_") %>% 
  select(-c(studyarm_val, date_visit1))
# A tibble: 30 × 6
     ids studyarm date_visit_1 date_visit_2 date_visit_3 date_visit_4
   <int> <chr>    <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>      
 1     1 arm1     2024-06-01   2024-06-15   2024-06-29   NA          
 2     2 arm2     2024-06-02   2024-06-16   2024-06-21   2024-11-29  
 3     3 arm3     2024-06-03   2024-06-17   2024-07-01   2024-07-05  
 4     4 arm1     2024-06-04   2024-06-18   2024-07-02   NA          
 5     5 arm2     2024-06-05   2024-06-19   2024-06-24   2024-12-02  
 6     6 arm3     2024-06-06   2024-06-20   2024-07-04   2024-07-08  
 7     7 arm1     2024-06-07   2024-06-21   2024-07-05   NA          
 8     8 arm2     2024-06-08   2024-06-22   2024-06-27   2024-12-05  
 9     9 arm3     2024-06-09   2024-06-23   2024-07-07   2024-07-11  
10    10 arm1     2024-06-10   2024-06-24   2024-07-08   NA          
# ℹ 20 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

